# capistrano's Capfile conditional require based on stage

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I want to require `capistrano/postgresql` only if stage is not production.
However, this Capfile always require `capistrano/postgresql` because `fetch(:stage)` is empty. 
( `puts fetch(:stage) || "no stage"` in Capfile prints "no stage")

```
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/npm'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/puma/nginx'
require 'capistrano/postgresql' unless fetch(:stage) == "production"
require 'capistrano/secrets_yml'
```

Should I put `require 'capistrano/postgresql'` in config/deploy/staging.rb etc.. (I don't know whether it works or not)?

Or is there any other concise way?

EDIT

If I put `require 'capistrano/postgresql'` in config/deploy/staging.rb, the following error appears.

```
WARNING: load:defaults has already been invoked and can no longer be modified.
Check that you haven't loaded a Capistrano plugin in deploy.rb by mistake.
Plugins must be loaded in the Capfile to initialize properly.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
can't modify frozen #<Class:#<Rake::Task:0x007fd8bcd22868>>
```

Comment: I might have time for a more comprehensive answer later, but I'd suggest trying to unregister the hooks if it is not production later in the process. Capistrano isn't fully booted in the Capfile.

Answer (score 3):

In Capefile add

```
task :use_postgresql do
  require 'capistrano/postgresql'
end

task 'staging' => [:use_postgresql]
```

In that way capistrano will use posgresql only on staging env